# How to Iterate Through List to Change URL?

Tags: python, list, loops, url

I would like to change the URL by iterating through a list. Any suggestions?

For example,

Let's say the URL is www.example/chi.com

The list of URLs is ['chi', 'den', 'lac']

The desired output that I am looking for is:

```
www.example/chi.com
www.example/den.com
www.example/lac.com
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
url = "www.example"
team = ["chi", 'den', 'lac']
dot_com = ".com"
for t in team:
    print(t)


print("{}/{}{}".format(url, t, dot_com))
```

Unfortunately the output that I have now looks like:

```
chi
den
lac
www.example/lac.com
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Put `print("{}/{}{}".format(url, t, dot_com))` inside the loop. And `dot_com = ".com"` in front of the loop of course. (Also delete the other print statement.)

Comment: This worked perfectly as you suggested. Thank you @mapf for your advice! Much appreciated sir. =) Would you like to add your response to the question so that I can award you the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just format them as you loop through them:

```
url = "www.example"
team = ["chi", 'den', 'lac']
for t in team:
    print(f"{url}/{t}.com")
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Jab! This code worked perfectly! =)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete this question in the preferred method thanks to @mapf and @Jab.

Here is the answer on printing multiple urls:

```
url = 'www.example'

teams = ['chi', 'den', 'lac']

dot_com = '.com'

for t in teams:
    print('{}/{}{}'.format(url, t, dot_com))
```